# Convert Base64 String to Bitmap or Image Xamarin or Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, base64

I'm trying to convert a Base64 string to an image and set ImageView using the same image. I know how to get it done in java, but I'm having a trouble in C#. Anyone have an idea of how to get it done in C#?

Some of the code I've tried;

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
 {
    // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Base64 to Bitmap :**

```
public Bitmap Base64ToBitmap(String base64String)
{
    byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.Decode(base64String, Base64Flags.Default);
    return BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.Length);
}
```

---

**Bitmap to Base64 :**

```
public String BitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 100, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.ToByteArray();
    return Base64.EncodeToString(byteArray, Base64Flags.Default);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Image to Base64 String**,
online conversion - [here](http://www.dailycoding.com/Utils/Converter/ImageToBase64.aspx)

```
 public string ImageToBase64(Image image, 
  System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

**Base64 String to Image**,
online conversion - [here](http://codebeautify.org/base64-to-image-converter)

```
    public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
    imageBytes.Length);

  // Convert byte[] to Image
  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Vishwesh I've tried this code, i get the following error ; 'Image' does not contain a definition for 'FromStream' .

Im using Visual Studio 2015 By the way.

Comment: `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes);` is enough. You don't need to `Write` to it. In this form, you must also set the position to 0 before passing to FromStream

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that your encoded data is some bitmap format?  If so, you should be able to do something like this:

```
public Bitmap Base64ToImage(string base64String)
 {
    // Convert base 64 string to byte[]
    byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    // Convert byte[] to Image
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length))
    {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.FromStream(ms, true);
        return image;
    }
 }
```